# New to programming - small part of program that am unable to solve

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and have been tasked with creating a program that collects and stores the data of cars in a car yard, in which the user inputs specific details of the car which are saved to the program and displayed at the end(make, model, year, price). The majority of the code works as intended and the boundaries I have put in place work. The problem is that when the user prompts to end the program by answering no to whether or not they want to add the details of another car, the program only displays one car in the summary. What should happen is that the program displays how many cars were entered into the system, the make, model and year of each car, and then what the cheapest car was. As stated before the program only displays data for the car most recently entered, instead of all of them. Please help me solve this as I have been stuck on it for a long while and can't seem to find a solution.
Thank you
Here is my current code:

```
def collect_car_data():
    lowest_price = float('inf')  # Set the lowest price variable to infinity
    cars = []  # Create an empty list to store car information
    incorrect_input_count = 0  # Initialize a counter for incorrect inputs
    while True:
        # Prompt the user to enter the make of the car
        car_make = input("Enter the make of the car, can't contain numbers or exceed 15 characters (0 to end): ").strip()
        
        if car_make == '0':
            break  # Exit the loop if the user enters '0'
        elif len(car_make) > 15 or any(char.isdigit() for char in car_make):
            # Check if the car make contains numbers or exceeds 15 characters
            print("Invalid car make. Please try again.")
            incorrect_input_count += 1
            
            if incorrect_input_count >= 3:
                # Terminate the program if there are too many incorrect inputs
                print("Failed to input a correct answer too many times. Program terminated.")
                return
            
        else:
            incorrect_input_count = 0
            break  # Exit the loop if the car make is valid
    
    while True:
        # Prompt the user to enter the model of the car
        car_model = input("Enter the model of the car, can't contain numbers or exceed 15 characters: ").strip()
        
        if len(car_model) > 15 or any(char.isdigit() for char in car_model):
            # Check if the car model contains numbers or exceeds 15 characters
            print("Invalid car model. Please try again.")
            incorrect_input_count += 1
            
            if incorrect_input_count >= 3:
                # Terminate the program if there are too many incorrect inputs
                print("Failed to input a correct answer too many times. Program terminated.")
                return
        else: 
            incorrect_input_count = 0
            break  # Exit the loop if the car model is valid
        
    while True:
        # Prompt the user to enter the year of the car
        car_year = input("Enter the year of the car, must contain 4 digits: ")
        
        if len(car_year) != 4 or not car_year.isdigit():
            # Check if the car year is not 4 digits or contains non-digit characters
            print("Invalid car year. Please try again.")
            incorrect_input_count += 1
            
            if incorrect_input_count >= 3:
                # Terminate the program if there are too many incorrect inputs
                print("Failed to input a correct answer too many times. Program terminated.")
                return
        else: 
            incorrect_input_count = 0
            break  # Exit the loop if the car year is valid
    
    while True:
        # Prompt the user to enter the ticket price of the car
        car_price = input("Enter the ticket price, must be between 1 and 1000000 (0 decimal places) $: ")
        
        if car_price.isdigit() and 1 < int(car_price) < 1000000:
            # Check if the car price is a positive integer within the specified range
            incorrect_input_count = 0
            break  # Exit the loop if the car price is valid
        else:
            print("Invalid ticket price. Please try again.")
            incorrect_input_count += 1
            
            if incorrect_input_count >= 3:
                # Terminate the program if there are too many incorrect inputs
                print("Failed to input a correct answer too many times. Program terminated.")
                return
    
    discount = int(car_price) * 0.10  # Calculate the discount amount as 10% of the car price
    net_sale_price = int(car_price) - discount  # Calculate the net sale price by subtracting the discount
    
    # Print the discount and net sale price of the car
    print(f"The discount for cash on this {car_year} {car_make} {car_model} is: $ {discount:.2f}")
    print(f"The net sale price of this car is: $ {net_sale_price:.2f}")
    
    while True:
        # Prompt the user to enter if they want to enter details for another car
        another_car = input("Do you want to enter details for another car? (yes/no): ")
        
        if another_car.lower() == "yes":
            # Add the car details to the cars list and continue to input details for another car
            collect_car_data()  # Call the function recursively to enter details for another car
            return  # Exit the function
        
        elif another_car.lower() == "no":
            print("Thank you for using our program!")
            cars.append(f"{car_year} {car_make} {car_model}")
            break  # Exit the loop if the user does not want to enter details for another car
        else:
            incorrect_input_count += 1
            
            if incorrect_input_count >= 3:
                # Terminate the program if there are too many incorrect inputs
                print("Failed to input a correct answer too many times. Program terminated.")
                return
            print("Incorrect input. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
    
    print(f"Number of cars you looked at: {len(cars)}")
    print("The cars you looked at were:")
    
    for car in cars:
        # Print the details of each car that was entered
        print(car)
        
    for car in cars:
        # Find the lowest net sale price among the entered cars
        if net_sale_price < lowest_price:
            lowest_price = net_sale_price
    
    print(f"The lowest net sale price was the {cars[0]} at: $ {lowest_price:.2f}") 
    return

collect_car_data()
```

I have tried many times to fix this by playing around with the relevant variables and their locations within the code, but am completely stuck and do not know what to do. What should happen is that when the user inputs no to whether or not they want to add another car, the program displays how many cars were entered into the system, the make, model and year of each car, and the cheapest car. What's happening is that it only says there was one car entered, and only displays the relevant info of the most recently added car. Please help, thank you.

Comment: As a side note, your boundaries are incorrect. I can not enter a BMW X5 because the model contains a number, and I can easily enter cars from the middle ages or from far in the future. just to mention a few things to improve.

Comment: from the looks of it, you are not adding the first input the user has given into the cars list. Once check it.

Comment: This function is too long. Refactor it and make own functions for each input.

Answer (score 0):

You make a recursive call to the function.

```
def collect_car_data():
    lowest_price = float('inf') 
    cars = []
```

Take a look at the second line of the function. What happens when you call it recursively? That's right, you RESET the array to be empty.

Another issue is here:

```
if another_car.lower() == "yes":
            # Add the car details to the cars list and continue to input details for another car
            collect_car_data()  # Call the function recursively to enter details for another car
            return  # Exit the function
```

Your comment says that you want to add it to the list, but you never do that

I understand that writing comments helps to understand the complicated programming language, but ultimately you're using them in the wrong way and it can be ultimately harmful, as has happened here. A program should be structured as such, and all names should be chosen as such, that comments become virtually unnecessary. But see more in the paragraph below.

Obviously, since you're a beginner, there are some other things in this code that could/should be improved before building bad habits. I suggest you fix the mistake so the program runs as intended and submit it over at codereview stackexchange to take further input on how to improve :)

Comment: What should I do to fix this? Sorry its 2am and my brain has completely lost all function

Comment: @HectorW get some sleep! You'll easily fix it in the morning.

Comment: BTW, codereview SE can be found at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you only append the car data if the user enters "no."

```
elif another_car.lower() == "no":
    print("Thank you for using our program!")
    cars.append(f"{car_year} {car_make} {car_model}")
    break  # Exit the loop if the user does not want to enter details for another car
```

you need to move the `append` in front of this `while` loop.  this also requires you include the "price" and change your `for` loop to determine the lowest price.

Answer (score 0):

As intermediate python Dev i could have used classes to implement the solution
and i could have tried something like this

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, price):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.price = price

car_inventory = []

def add_car():
    make = input("Enter the car's make: ")
    model = input("Enter the car's model: ")
    year = input("Enter the car's year: ")
    price = input("Enter the car's price: ")
    car = Car(make, model, year, price)
    car_inventory.append(car)
    print("Car added successfully.")

def display_cars():
    print("Car Inventory:")
    for index, car in enumerate(car_inventory):
        print(f"Car {index+1}:")
        print(f"Make: {car.make}")
        print(f"Model: {car.model}")
        print(f"Year: {car.year}")
        print(f"Price: {car.price}")
        print()

def main():
    while True:
        print("1. Add a car")
        print("2. Display cars")
        print("3. Exit")
        choice = input("Enter your choice (1-3): ")
        if choice == '1':
            add_car()
        elif choice == '2':
            display_cars()
        elif choice == '3':
            print("Exiting the program.")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm very sorry but where would I implement this into my code? Just to see how that would work so I can learn from it. Thank you